# PHP GD Extension is not loaded on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, php, php-gd

PHP GD Extension is loaded and working on local server but it is not loaded correctly on our live server even though I am using all the exact same files.

(PHP GD is working fine here)
Local Server: Microsoft Windows Server 2003 For Small Business Server SP2
IIS Version: 6

Then I copied the whole "C:\PHP" folder from local server to "C:\Program Files (x86)\" on live server. That "PHP" folder does include ext folder and "php_gd2.dll" file inside it. I changed the path from "C:\PHP" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\" in "php.ini" too. However, PHP is not loaded on live server.

```
PHPINFO Local:http://jsfiddle.net/hFKfx/
PHPINFO Live: http://jsfiddle.net/h77Hy/
```

I am not very good with PHP. Please help.

Comment: As it is an installation/migration question rather than programming, it may be more suitable for [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I wish I could move this question to that server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Win2K3 / IIS6, you're running PHP as a ISAPI module (thread-safe).
In Win 7 / IIS7.5, you're running PHP as a FCGI module (non-thread-safe).

This is likely your problem. You can't mix and match thread-safe (TS) / non-thread-safe (NTS) extensions with core PHP. If you just copied everything over, you probably have TS extensions. You need to download and use the NTS ones.

([archive link to PHP 5.2.6 NTS](http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/php-5.2.6-nts-Win32.zip))

To verify this assumption, check where *php.ini* specifies a log for startup errors. If you're logging startup errors, you should see something similar to:

> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: gd Extension: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with build ID=API20041225,TS,VC6
>   PHP    compiled with build ID=API20041225,NTS,VC6
>   These options need to match

*(note "TS" vs "NTS")*

Hope that helps. If not, maybe you'll find something else in the log that indicates what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry again for being so noob. I just downloaded that zip file and overwrote everything to PHP folder. Now it turns out "Loaded Configuration File  (none)". I changed file name from "php.ini-recommended" to "php.ini". The configuration file isn't loaded too. :( Should I change "FCGI" module to "IsapiModule"? Thanks.

Comment: FCGI vs ISAPI isn't a simple configuration change; it's how PHP is set up in IIS. Did you ever find the PHP log to see if there were any startup errors?

Comment: OMG. I messed up everything. Even, PHPMyAdmin isn't working now. It says "Cannot load mysql extension. Please check your PHP configuration. - Documentation". I cannot see any extension in phpinfo() now. I ran "php.exe" and it doesn't show any error.

Comment: Jesus! I got mysql back. I'd better stop playing around today and leave it until weekend. Thanks for everything Wiseguy.

Comment: WOW That's fantasitc. As soon as I fixed mysql extension, GD extension is also loaded automatically. Brovo Wiseguy.